# Group and count JSON using jq

Tags: json, group-by, jq, data-manipulation, counting

I am trying to convert the following JSON into a csv which has each unique "name" and the total count (i.e: number of times that name appears).

### Current data:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "name": "hello"
  },
  {
    "name": "hello"
  }
]
```

### Ideal output:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "hello",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "test",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

I've tried `[.[] | group_by (.name)[] ]` but get the following error:

> jq: error (at :11): Cannot index string with string "name"

JQ play link: https://jqplay.org/s/fWqNUii1b2

Note, I am already using jq to format the initial raw data into the format above. Please see the JQ play link here: https://jqplay.org/s/PwwRYscmBK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
group_by(.name) 
    | map({name: .[0].name, count: length})
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "hello",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

### [Jq▷Play](https://jqplay.org/s/BbTsCyTPCy)

---

Based on OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641816/group-and-count-json-using-jq/66641987?noredirect=1#comment117806635_66641987), use the following jq filter to count each name across multiple objects, where the `.name` is nested.

```
map(.labels) 
    | map({name: .[0].name, count: length})
```

[Jq▷Play](https://jqplay.org/s/XNVHIvTfVk)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work in isolation. How would you combine it with `[.[] | {name: .labels[].name} ]` which formats the raw data into the initial format needed?

Comment: Please share the 'initial format' so we can play with it ;)

Comment: Added, see link to jqplay at bottom of original post.

Comment: Do you want to count the names in each object? Or are you looking for a way to count those for each object seperated?

Comment: exactly the latter - across objects. It doesn't really matter to me which object the name is associated with, I just want to know how many objects have each name.

Comment: Please take a look at the new part of my answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '[{"name": "test"}, {"name": "hello"}, {"name": "hello"}]' | jq 'group_by (.name)[] | {name: .[0].name, count: length}' | jq -s
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "hello",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: OP needs those 2 objects inside an array.

Comment: @0stone0 oh, you're right! Fixed!